# Is it OK to keep OAuth access token in user's cookie?

Tags: asp.net, security, oauth

I think that it's ok, but I thought I would see what others think.

Specifically, the token string would be part of the userdata string of an asp.net FormsAuthentication ticket, and therefore would be encrypted. Of couse the associated scecret would not be stored in any cookie.

Comment: It should be okay as long as you are unsetting the cookie after user log-out, or when the session is invalidated. However, its not best practice, and should be avoided if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical problem with storing the OAuth access token in a user's cookie in some scenarios. Scenarios such as where you only are accessing the protected resources during the life of the session and there is no expectation that the ability to access the protected resource would remain over user sessions.